# What can limit dex for AC?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

This is possibly a bug in *Hero Lab* but it's been pretty solid so far; so I'm trying to work out what it's doing. If it is a hero lab bug, then this question will probably need to be deleted.

I've created a Tiny creature race template with a racial dex mod of +4.
The PC in question has a base dex of 10, with racial this gives 14 (+2)
The creature also has a natural armour mod of +4 (It's a dragon)

But the base AC of the creature is listed as 17 (+1 dex +2 size +4 natural)

(This has also affected CM defence in the same way, incidentally)

The initiative modifier for the character is (correctly) calculated as +2.

The character has no armour on or any other effects I can think of.

So; the question (finally!):

What, apart from armour, can restrict the dexterity bonus to AC?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Encumbrance.**

[Check his load](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity) against his Strength score. If he is in heavy load, his maximum Dexterity bonus is +1.

Being Tiny, he has a carrying capacity equal to 1/2 of the carrying capacity of a Medium-sized creature with the same Strength. Of course, most of his equipment should weigh less too. Check if you gave him armor and weapons appropriate for his size.

Comment: That's it! Ta-da! Dooooh. The vast piles of cash I gave him kind of weighed him down! Cheers! Note, leaving this question open for a while however, in case there are any other factors so the question can be more informative.